# IE: How to display absolute positioned divs under a relative positioned div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

currently I'm creating a layout, which requires a div having background graphics and the top and the bottom. My mark-up which I created works fine in FF and looks like this:

[image]

```
#wrapper {
width: 520px;
padding: 2px;
position: relative;
float: left;
z-index: 4000;
}

#upper_bg {
    background:url(images/header_top.png);
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:520px;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: -2px;
}

#row_wrapper {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    z-index: 3000;
}

#lower_bg {
    background:url(images/header_bottom.png);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:200px;
    width:520px;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: -2px;
}

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="upper_bg">
      <!-- ie fix for displaying empty divs -->
   </div>
   <div id="row_wrapper">
      ... content!
   </div>
   <div id="lower_bg">
      <!-- -->
   </div>
</div>
```

In IE (7,8 & 9) however the upper and lower_bg divs are invisible. Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Please stop using positioning for such constructions. Floating is much simpler, better and more flexible solution. Also check if your website isn't rendered in quirks mode, this often causes problems in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Your example looks nothing like that for me so there must be something missing. Can you create a jsfiddle or give a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the problem. Indeed, the shown html in my question didn't reproduce the result. After a bit fiddling, I found out that IE was in quirks mode. I created the html via xslt and forgott to add the xsl:output tag and set it to html. After doing so, IE was fine down to version 7 with the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add a clear...

```
<div id="lower_bg">
      blabla floating divs
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```